# How to open xib or storyboard window in MyScene (which is subclass of SKScene)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, transition

I want to implement "In App Purchases" and in my game when the game is played I have sprite that works as button. When uses presses that button I want some kind of storyboard or xib window or view would appear and there would be buttons one "Buy" and the other "Restore Purchase". From MyScene I would like to open new window where player would buy something. I now how to create new file => make it subclass of UIViewController => also add xib file (so I could open that window form MyScene) which would create new class. But how do I call that storyboard or xib in MyScene so the window would pup up. I know how to create new Scene and even transition to that new scene but I dont know how to present viewController window or view. Please help!!

Comment: Could you give some sample code. Please be as detailed as possible, I am new to programming and if I miss someting I would not be able to do it. For example, where we need to import some class, where we   must create property and details like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a UIView and attach it to your existing ViewControllers View, or present another ViewController as modal.

The first could as well be the view of another ViewController or a XIB and can be customized as you will.
The latter would, by default, be presented in Fullscreen (at least on the iPhone)

Comment: Yes I know how I need to create new viewController class but how do I get the player from MyScene to that class  where all buttons will be like "buy" "restore". Please give me sample code.